# Django : Foreign Key to a choice field model

Tags: django

I am relatively new to Python / Django.

I am trying to create a relationship between food items and the category (name)
they belong:

```
class Category(models.Model):
    options=(
        ('vegetable','vegetable'),
        ('fruit','fruit'),
        ('carbs','carbs'),
        ('fish','fish'),
        ('meat', 'meat'),
        ('sweet', 'sweet'),
        ('dairy', 'dairy'),
    )
    name=models.CharField(max_length=10,choices=options,unique=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Fooditem(models.Model):

    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

The code above throws error when running migrate:
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'vegetable'

I created some items in the database, is it the reason?

What is the best way to solve this problem?
Thank you,
D

Comment: I think the problem originates  somewhere else (in migrations):
Running migrations:
  Applying Fityfeed.0013_auto_20210310_2221...Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\DenisBidinost\PycharmProjects\Calories\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\__init__.py", line 1774, in get_prep_value
    return int(value)
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'vegetable'

Comment: 0013_auto_20210310_2221:
    operations = [
        migrations.RemoveField(
            model_name='fooditem',
            name='category',
        ),
        migrations.AddField(
            model_name='fooditem',
            name='category',
            field=models.ForeignKey(default='vegetable', on_delete=django.db.models.deletion.CASCADE, to='Fityfeed.category'),
        ),
    ]

Comment: I think I have done changes in the past and the migrations files are trying to recover something that is not valid anymore... I would gladly start from scratch (i.e. clean all database changes I have done) but is it at all possible? 
Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: I have now tried to rebuild teh project from scratch...

Answer (score 0):

It would fix it, but you may have some unexpected results.

```
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

will be an id pointing to the other model.

You can make name the primary key by changing it to the following:

```
    name=models.CharField(max_length=10,choices=options,unique=True,primary_key=True)
```

Also reviewing https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/fields/#choices more closely may help you with your options down the road. It will programming easier to define as costants and follow thier syntaxing

Answer (score 0):

I would realy recommend u to do it this way. if there is something that is unclear just let me know

````
class Category(models.TextChoices):
   
    vegetable='vegetable'
    fruit='fruit'
    carbs='carbs'
    fish='fish'
    meat='meat'
    sweet='sweet'
    dairy='dairy'
   

class Fooditem(models.Model):

    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    category = models.CharField(max_length=20, choices=Category.choices)```
````

Comment: Hello 
After re-building from scratch, I have applied your suggested changes,
 but it fails when trying to register for admin:

  File "C:\Users\DenisBidinost\PycharmProjects\Calories_New\Fityfeed\admin.py", line 14, in <module>
    admin.site.register(Category)
  File "C:\Users\DenisBidinost\PycharmProjects\Calories_New\venv\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\sites.py", line 106, in register
    if model._meta.abstract:
AttributeError: 'Category' object has no attribute '_meta'

Comment: can u inculde the code so i can see if u made any mistakes

Comment: Hello  
I have open another question:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66604764/django-textchoices-and-admin-site-register  
I have been told there that I cannot register a TextChoices to admin... is it true?  
Thanks so much for your help ,any pointer to learn more is very appreciated.   
It seems quite complicated for such a simple thing: assign a category to fooditems  
that can be changed in admin or user....