# Django - Textchoices and admin.site.register

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have a choice class TextChoices:

```
class Category(models.TextChoices):
    vegetable = 'VEG', 'vegetable'
    fruit = 'FRT', 'fruit'
    carbs = 'CRB', 'carbs'
    fish = 'FSH', 'fish'
    meat = 'MT', 'meat'
    sweet = 'SWT', 'sweet'
    dairy = 'DRY', 'dairy'
    ready = 'RDY', 'ready'

    # def __str__(self):
    #     return self.name
    def __str__(self):
        return self.choices
```

Used in:

```
class Fooditem(models.Model):

    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    #    category = models.ManyToManyField(Category)
    category = models.CharField(max_length=3, choices=Category.choices, default=Category.vegetable)
```

Now, I would like to make Category editable by admin:

```
admin.site.register(Category)
```

But I have the following error:

```
  File "PycharmProjects\Calories_New\Fityfeed\admin.py", line 14, in <module>
    admin.site.register(Category)
  File "PycharmProjects\Calories_New\venv\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\sites.py", line 106, in register
    if model._meta.abstract:
AttributeError: 'Category' object has no attribute '_meta'
```

I am relatively new in Django and would appreciate your help, also in understanding
how I can solve these problems myself (struggling with reference documentation).

Comment: If categories are going to be added dynamically you want to be using a separate model for that and have a foreign key to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since categories can be added dynamically it should be a `Model`:

```py
class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=35)
```

Next to make the relationship between `Category` and `Fooditem` you want to use a [`ForeignKey` [Django docs]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/fields/#foreignkey):

```py
class Fooditem(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="food_items")
```

To access a Food items category:

```py
print(food_item_instance.category.name) # Outputs "vegetable" or whatever the category is.
```

Also to get each food item in a category:

```py
food_items = category_instance.food_items.all()
```

Now you can register `Category` to the admin site since it is a model.

Comment: Thank you very much @Abdul very kind.   
If I apply the changes and then use the admin interface:  
class foodAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):  
    class Meta:  
        model=Fooditem  
    list_display=['name']  
    list_filter=['name']  
admin.site.register(Category)  
admin.site.register(Fooditem,foodAdmin)

Comment: When I try to delete a category or list the fooditems I get the following error:   
Exception Value: 
no such column: Fityfeed_fooditem.category_id  

What is wrong?  
Thank you very much for your kind answer   
D

Comment: @dbidinost looks like you already have some data in that table. Also when one changes the models one needs to migrate. I assume that the data in your table is not very important and you have just started in this case you can simply delete the database file and the migrations (leave the folder and the file `__init__.py`). In other cases making such changes might be a little complicated. After doing this just migrate again `python manage.py makemigrations` and `python manage.py migrate`